# Chrome Extension: Hide API Key

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I'm developing a Chrome Extension where I need to use APIs which require id/keys. As anyone can easily look into the source code of extension, is there a way to hide the API access information from the user?

After searching, I found: [Securing website API keys in Chrome extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577110/securing-website-api-keys-in-chrome-extensions?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

This thread was created three years ago and has an answer that the only option is to use something similar to a custom webservice call. Is something changed? Or a custom webservice is the **only option**?

This thread too didnt provide much info: [How to secure an API key in a Google chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929004/how-to-secure-an-api-key-in-a-google-chrome-extension)

Comment: never put secrets in client-side code, even if view-source is harder to get to than normal...

Comment: I think this is a chicken-and-egg problem. The user of your extension is allowed to call that API - what's the point of hiding the credentials then? If you want to impose limits, there's no way to do that reliably on the client side - make your own proxy API as suggested and pre-filter requests on your server.

Comment: What georg said. If the API key is individual per user, then you can store it on the users machine - it's his anyway and other people can't get it from there. If it's the same key for everybody, what's the point of the key?